# How to "auto format" date in mui DatePicker with mm/yyyy format?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I've been working with mui DatePciker with `mm/yyyy` format. The thing is that I want the slash to appear automatically if the user writes by itself, like it happens with `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

I've checked the documentation and changing the examples that are given but I can't make it work.

Here is the example I am workig on: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-parm-70mcsq?file=/demo.tsx

Example image:
[image: datePicker-example]

As you can see in the image the first DatePicker has the format `mm/yyyy`, I wrote it by myself and this is what I get `032021` instead of `03/2021` whereas in the second DatePicker the slashes are added automatically while writing the date `12/12/`

How can I replicate automatically adding the slashes behaviour? Thank you!

CODE:

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function ViewsDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(dayjs("2022-04-07"));

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DatePicker
          views={["year", "month"]}
          inputFormat="MM/YYYY" //Added prop
          label="Year and Month"
          minDate={dayjs("2012-03-01")}
          maxDate={dayjs("2023-06-01")}
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
        />
        <DatePicker
          openTo="year"
          views={["year", "month", "day"]}
          label="Year, month and date"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found an answer that works. It can be fixed with this two props:

```
mask="__/____"
disableMaskedInput={false}
```

This two must be added, only with `mask` doesn't work.

Answer and more explanation found here: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4664